# How to have a redirect using header(location: url) in php when click on a <a>text</a>?

Tags: php, html, session

I want to use this because i have to maintain a session.
I tried in this way but the function is being executed immediately when the page is opened:

```
 <a onclick="myfunction();">text</a>
```

Function:

```
function myfunction()
{
  <?php
       header("location: page.php");
       exit;
  ?>
}
```

I tried also with forms and buttons but isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="redirect.php">text</a>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['smth']){
       header("location: page.php");
   } else {
      // to do what you want
   }
?>
```

Comment: I tried. in this way the $_SESSION in page.php doesn't work

Comment: Part of source pages posted